# iTextSharp permissions always 0 when reading certificate protected file

Tags: c#, itext

In iTextSharp 5.5.10, when opening a PDF document that is protected with a certificate, the `Permissions` value of the `PdfReader` class is always 0.

I had a look at the (iTextSharp) source code and it seems that this value is never assigned for certificate protected files.  I did find [this](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.dotnet.itextsharp.general/2008-02/msg00056.html) link where somebody has written code to read these permissions, but I'm not sure whether it is correct (and it was written against an older version of iTextSharp).  Is there any reason why the permissions were omitted in this case?